# Dns do not resolves domains other than configured zones on that dns

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos7

Configured DNS as an Authoritative Name Server with 2 slaves (catch only)

the problem is that DNS do not seems to be resolving other domains , only domains configured in that DNS, as far I understand it must resolve other domains as well using the list of the ROOT servers in named.conf

```
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

This is my named conf

```
options { 
        listen-on port 53 { any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid";
        allow-query     { any; };
        version "Bind";                                 
        allow-transfer { 10.0.0.4; 10.0.0.5; 192.168.1.35; };
        recursion no;
        auth-nxdomain no;   
    dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};
logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};
acl common-allow-transfer {
    none;
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

and

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search ups.local
nameserver 10.0.0.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If I'm removing google dns no external domains are getting resolver

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option [`recursion no;`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#boolean_options) in your configuration explicitly disables the support for resolving non-local names (through recursion).

I would suggest also reading up on the [`allow-recursion` and related settings](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) to change who is allowed to make use of this.

It's worth noting that overriding `allow-query` in the way that you did (`allow-query { any; };`)  is probably not a good idea as doing so also affects the defaults of other `allow-*` settings (see link above for details).

Comment: ur rights bout allow-querry, changed it to  allow-recursion {
  localnets;
 };